# How to setup blazor server google place autocomplete address form

Tags: google-maps, blazor, google-places-api, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor and trying to set up an [address form to use google place autocomplete](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform#all). I have done this web and mobile before.

I am not sure how to:

- Call the javascript from the blazor component.
- Populate the address fields from the selected address.
- Save the data in the fields to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get working with the code below. For the complete solution see github [repo](https://github.com/MSIH/Blazor-Radzen-Google-Places-Autocomplete). Here is the [demo](https://blazorradzengoogleplacesautocomplete.azurewebsites.net/) site.

1. \Shared\_Host.cshmtl

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEYI&libraries=places"></script>
    </head>
```

2. \wwwroot\js\serverSideScripts.js

```js
    window.initAutocomplete = () => {

    let autocomplete;
    let address1Field;
    let address2Field;
    let postalField;

    fillInAddress = (autocomplete) => {

        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        let address1 = "";
        let postcode = "";

        // Get each component of the address from the place details,
        // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
        // place.address_components are google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent objects
        // which are documented at http://goo.gle/3l5i5Mr
        if (place) {
            for (const component of place.address_components) {
                const componentType = component.types[0];

                switch (componentType) {
                    case "street_number": {
                        address1 = `${component.long_name} ${address1}`;
                        break;
                    }

                    case "route": {
                        address1 += component.short_name;
                        break;
                    }

                    case "postal_code": {
                        postcode = `${component.long_name}${postcode}`;
                        break;
                    }

                    case "postal_code_suffix": {
                        postcode = `${postcode}-${component.long_name}`;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "locality":
                        document.querySelector("#locality").value = component.long_name;
                        break;

                    case "administrative_area_level_1": {
                        document.querySelector("#state").value = component.short_name;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "country":
                        document.querySelector("#country").value = component.long_name;
                        break;
                }
            }
            address1Field.value = address1;
            postalField.value = postcode;
            // After filling the form with address components from the Autocomplete
            // prediction, set cursor focus on the second address line to encourage
            // entry of subpremise information such as apartment, unit, or floor number.
            address2Field.focus();
        }
    }


    address1Field = document.querySelector("#ship-address");
    address2Field = document.querySelector("#address2");
    postalField = document.querySelector("#postcode");
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
    // addresses in the US and Canada.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address1Field, {
        componentRestrictions: { country: ["us", "ca"] },
        fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
        types: ["address"],
    });
    address1Field.focus();
    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", function () { fillInAddress(autocomplete) });
     
    
}
```

3. \Pages\GoogleAutoComplete.razor

```cs
@page "/AddressAutocompleteForm"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>

<style type="text/css">
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
        * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #686868;
    }

    form {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
        max-width: 400px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1.2rem;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

        input:focus {
            border-bottom: 4px solid black;
        }

        input[type="reset"] {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            border-bottom: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            color: #686868;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

    .title {
        width: 100%;
        margin-block-end: 0;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .note {
        width: 100%;
        margin-block-start: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .form-label {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

    .full-field {
        flex: 400px;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }

    .slim-field-left {
        flex: 1 150px;
        margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    }

    .slim-field-right {
        flex: 1 150px;
        margin: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
    }

    .my-button {
        background-color: #000;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 6px 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .my-button:hover {
            background-color: #666;
        }

        .my-button:active {
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
        }
</style>



<!-- Note: The address components in this sample are based on North American address format. You might need to adjust them for the locations relevant to your app. For more information, see
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
    -->

<form id="address-form" action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <p class="title">Sample address form for North America</p>
    <p class="note"><em>* = required field</em></p>
    <label class="full-field">
        <!-- Avoid the word "address" in id, name, or label text to avoid browser autofill from conflicting with Place Autocomplete. Star or comment bug https://crbug.com/587466 to request Chromium to honor autocomplete="off" attribute. -->
        <span class="form-label">Deliver to*</span>
        <input id="ship-address"
               name="ship-address"
               required
               autocomplete="off" />
    </label>
    <label class="full-field">
        <span class="form-label">Apartment, unit, suite, or floor #</span>
        <input id="address2" name="address2" />
    </label>
    <label class="full-field">
        <span class="form-label">City*</span>
        <input id="locality" name="locality" required />
    </label>
    <label class="slim-field-left">
        <span class="form-label">State/Province*</span>
        <input id="state" name="state" required />
    </label>
    <label class="slim-field-right" for="postal_code">
        <span class="form-label">Postal code*</span>
        <input id="postcode" name="postcode" required />
    </label>
    <label class="full-field">
        <span class="form-label">Country/Region*</span>
        <input id="country" name="country" required />
    </label>
    <button type="button" class="my-button">Save address</button>

    <!-- Reset button provided for development testing convenience.
    Not recommended for user-facing forms due to risk of mis-click when aiming for Submit button. -->
    <input type="reset" value="Clear form" />
</form>


@functions {


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initAutocomplete");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And how exactly are you accessing the input data from Blazor? Please, show us...

Comment: @enet not sure what you are asking. This code does not save the address data to the backend. The click side for the address autocomplete is pure JavaScript.